# iTunes connect does not accept my large app icon

Tags: ios, icons, app-store-connect

I have submitted a large app icon to iTunes Connect that meets all the specifications: .png file, 1024x1024 pixels, etc. and yet I still get the 
error:

> "The large app icon you uploaded is not valid. It must be a .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png file that is 1024 x 1024 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space."

I created it using Photoshop Elements. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Update - problem solved:

I have tried it again. It worked. Did not need to se exported as PNG or TIF and I am not sure exactly what was different this time (after 4 hours of trying), but it uploaded.

Comment: Did you export the image as a png file or did you simply rename the file with a png extension?

Comment: Try exporting it as a tif as a test to see if it accepts that.  PNGs can be exported in a few different internal formats, I've never encountered an issue with iTunes submission regarding this but may be an issue if you've got some obscure plugin.

Comment: I had the same issue. It seems iTunes Connect doesn't work well with Windows XP. I have tried Firefox, Safari and Chrome on Windows XP and none of them worked. It works perfectly fine on Mac OS X or Windows 7. I have checked this with the same image on different operating systems.

Comment: I've got the same problem right now. I even downloaded a LArge App Icon from another app I have already successfully submitted and it got rejected. Have tried Chrome and Safari on Mac. I think something must be wrong with their site.

Comment: Just to confirm my comment above, there WAS a problem at Apple's end. I raised a ticket and they fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The command below is a hack to base-line PNG images and format them "them 
Apple way". Use the following in command line (Terminal), changing "/path/to/image/folder/" to match the location of your PNG files:

```
sips --deleteColorManagementProperties /path/to/image/folder/*.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the part about the RGB color space in the requirements. Maybe your file was saved as CMYK originally?

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur if you changed the extension of image by changing name (forcefully from image.jpg to image.png) and you have not exported image to that format.

Simply exporting the image to that format will resolve your issue. You can use 512x512 or 1024x1024 RGB color space image with 72dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Save it with "Not Interlaced" option cos I think it doesn't accept Interlaced PNGs

Answer (score 0):

For those who have noscript or else active. Allow apple.com or otherwise you will just get "Your file could not be loaded. Try again." over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried a lot of different image sizes 1024, 512, jpg, png... First they were all in wrong CMYK color mode. Then I tried jpg with RGB, did not work

and FINALLY:

.PNG 1024x1024px with color mode "RGB" worked

Answer (score 0):

Your Icon File has to be saved with the configuration below:

- size 1024 x 1024 pixel with resolution max 72 dpi
- your image / picture has no alpha colour (uncheck the alpha checklist)
- no transparency, no rounded corner
- save in PNG or JPEG format